# Github PR's merged commit author is overriden by Github main email address

Tags: github, git-merge, pull-request

I need to use two separate email addresses in Github for different purposes. In order to achieve this, I have added a secondary email to my account and I author my git commits with this exact same secondary email. The problem is that if I open some Pull Request which has my secondary email as the commits author, and then someone else approves the PR and makes a "Squash & Merge" or "Rebase & Merge" through the Github web interface, then the final merged commit author is overriden with my Github account's main email address.

I tried opening a new PR in which commits have my secondary email as author. If i merge the PR myself then I can select which email Github will use as author, but if someone else does the "Squash & Merge" or "Rebase & Merge" it then overrides the commit author with my Github account's main email address. I want it to use some secondary email address.